# How to Get the ConnectionString that the Membership Provider is using?

Tags: asp.net, connection-string, membership-provider

... and not by reading it from the config file! Nor inferring it from anyplace other than be reading exactly what the Membership Provider is itself using. Call me paranoid.

The first data access in my application is an access to the membership provider. The vast majority of connectivity issues have been where the application is deployed to staging or production with a connection string from development, so I'd like to change this:

```
MembershipUser me = Membership.GetUser();
```

to this:

```
MembershipUser me;

try
{
    me = Membership.GetUser();
}

catch ( SqlException E )
{
    Response.Write( "SQL Error " + E.Message + ".<br />" );
    Response.Write( "Connection String: " + Membership.Provider.WHAT? + "<br />" );
}
```

Seems so obvious, but every reference I find instructs me to use the `ConfigurationManager`, which is what I specifically *don't* want to do. Although I concede that such may be my only option, and a satisfactory one at that.

I'm perfectly willing to accept the possibility that my question is on par with this:

```
int i;

try
{
    i = 42;
}

catch ( Exception e )
{
    Response.Write( "Error assigning literal to integer." );    
}
```

If this is the case, please comment accordingly.

Comment: Before you make any changes to your code, perhaps you could do something to make your deployment process more robust? I recommend creating web.config transforms for your different environments (development, staging, production etc.) to reduce the risk of forgetting to change environment-dependent settings (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a direct property that you can use that will give you the connection information.  One thing you could do though is subclass your chosen membership provider and implement your own properties to give you the info.

Comment: The _sqlConnectionString field of the SqlMembershipProvider is private. You have to rely on reflection to get it.

Comment: Agreed.  Here's a blog post that shows an example of doing this, albeit in order to dynamically set the connection string rather than view it, but the idea is the same...
http://devspade.com/index.php/2010/06/28/using-dynamic-connection-strings-with-the-asp-net-sql-membership-provider/

Answer (score 0):

It's generally considered a bad idea to surface connection strings in the UI (i.e. poor security) which is why you won't find readily available properties to pass on the value from classes that have read it from the config file.

You may want to consider addressing the root cause of the problem which is related to deployment. This problem is easily solved by using different configuration files for development, staging and production. Visual Studio has built-in support for automatically managing the deployment of the appropriate config file. Full details here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hi Here is a way to **get connection string from or by the specified Provider Name** (ex MySQL provider).

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Web.Security;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Reflection;


void SomeFunction()
{

  Type t = Membership.Provider.GetType();
  FieldInfo fi = null;
  while (fi == null && t != null)
  {
       fi = t.GetField("connectionString", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
       t = t.BaseType;
  }

  MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider a =(MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;

  string Connection_String_Value= fi.GetValue(a).ToString();

}
```

- By replace 'connectionString' with other Non-Public field name You
  can Access its Value too.
- By replacing Provider(default) with
  Membership.Providers["Name_Of_Your_Provider"] you can get its
  connection string too.